# Pass a function as argument to a process target with Pool.map()

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm developing a software to benchmark some scripts Python using different methods (mono-thread, multi-threads, multi-processes). So I need to execute the same function (with same arguments, etc...) in differents processes.

How to pass the function to execute as argument to a process target ?

What I currently understand is that a reference to a function cannot work because the function referenced is not visible for other processes, that's why I tried with a custom manager for the shared memory.

Here a simplified code:

```
#!/bin/python

from multiprocessing import Pool
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager
from itertools import repeat

class FunctionManager(BaseManager):
    pass

def maFunction(a, b):
    print(a + b)

def threadedFunction(f_i_args):
    (f, i, args) = f_i_args
    f(*args)

FunctionManager.register('Function', maFunction)

myManager = FunctionManager()
myManager.start()

myManager.Function(0, 0) # Test 1
threadedFunction((maFunction, 0, (1, 1))) # Test 2

p = Pool()
args = zip(repeat(myManager.Function), range(10), repeat(2, 2))
p.map(threadedFunction, args) # Does not work
p.join()

myManager.shutdown()
```

The current pickling error at "p.map()" is the following :

```
2
0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 27, in <module>
    p.map(threadedFunction, args) # Does not work
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 260, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 608, in get
    raise self._value
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 385, in _handle_tasks
    put(task)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 206, in send
    self._send_bytes(ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 50, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'weakref'>: attribute lookup weakref on builtins failed
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got a bit different error from running your code. Your key problem I think is that you pass a function to FunctionManager.register() instead of a class.  I also had to remove your zip to make it work and create a list manually, but this you can probably fix. This is just an example.

The following code works and does something using your exact structure. I would do this a bit differently and not use BaseManager, but I assume you have your reasons.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.5

from multiprocessing import Pool
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager
from itertools import repeat

class FunctionManager(BaseManager):
    pass


class maClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def maFunction(self,a, b):
        print(a + b)

def threadedFunction(f_i_args):
    (f, i, args) = f_i_args
    f(*args)

FunctionManager.register('Foobar', maClass)

myManager = FunctionManager()
myManager.start()
foobar = myManager.Foobar()

foobar.maFunction(0, 0) # Test 1
threadedFunction((foobar.maFunction, 0, (1, 1))) # Test 2

p = Pool()
#args = list(zip(repeat(foobar.maFunction), range(10), repeat(2, 2)))
args = []
for i in range(10):
    args.append([foobar.maFunction, i, (i,2)])


p.map(threadedFunction, args) # Does now work
p.close()
p.join()

myManager.shutdown()
```

Or did I misunderstand your problem completely?

Hannu

Comment: Thanks for your answer. maFunction is defined at top-level and I can't change that. I've found a way that seems "to work": http://pastebin.com/GNB7ZybS. But with your solution (and hence the one linked too), all the processes together don't use more than one logical core. CPU usage is stuck at 12.5% (I've 8 logical cores). Maybe it's Manager related? How would you do differently?

Comment: Actually, the problem is reproducable here: http://pastebin.com/56ALQqJk

Comment: No. Because using numpy can solve a Global Interpreter Lock?

Comment: No, but there is a feature in Numpy that seems to limit you to one core. I stumbled across it some time ago. Just thought to ask in case that would have explained your 12,5% issue.

Comment: Let's accept your answer, it's just that I have another issue, so I'm gonna ask another question. Thanks for your help!