# Multiprocesses seem to use a single logical core

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to execute a shared function that different processes can call. The only way found, is to create a class containing this function (see [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40603644/pass-a-function-as-argument-to-a-process-target-with-pool-map/)). But now the problem I'm facing is that the processes seem to wait for something, thus using only the power of a single logical core (see the image).

I've succeed to reproduce the same problem with the following code (it has been simplified):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from multiprocessing import Pool
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager
from itertools import repeat

class FunctionManager(BaseManager):
    pass

class MaClass:
    def maFunction(self, val):
        print(str(val))
        for i in range(0, 10000):
            for j in range(0, 10000):
                for k in range(0, 10000):
                    pass

FunctionManager.register('MaClass', MaClass)

myManager = FunctionManager()
myManager.start()
monObjet = myManager.MaClass()

p = Pool()
p.imap_unordered(monObjet.maFunction, range(10))
p.close()
p.join()

myManager.shutdown()
```

[image: HTOP CPU USAGE]

Any ideas?

Comment: Python does not (yet) support true multithreaded parallel execution *within one interpreter instance*. You can launch several Python interpreters and thus achieve a context in which multiple threads are running concurrently without blocking each other.

Comment: @Ukimiku he is using the `multiprocessing` module.

Comment: it is not threads but _processes_. It seems to run normally. But 10 processes would need 10 cores to run at 100% CPU each.

Comment: Why do you need a shared function? That function is literally shared. Because you are using a shared function object through a manager, the child processes only see proxies to that function and those proxies run the function back in the parent. Normally, you run a pool without a manager - then it runs the function directly in the child.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`monObject` is not a regular class instance, its a proxy `<class 'multiprocessing.managers.AutoProxy[MaClass]'>` to the instance. When child processes call that proxy, the request goes back to the parent where it is processed. The background threads doing the proxy are still subject to the GIL so, no matter how many child processes call it, it can only execute one of these threads at a time.

Its uncommon to run a proxy method inside a pool. I appreciate that you've just cooked up an example and may really need to run the method in the parent, but here is a straw man example that keeps the work in the child

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from multiprocessing import Pool

def worker(val):
    c = MaClass()
    return c.maFunction(val)

class MaClass:
    def maFunction(self, val):
        print(str(val))
        for i in range(0, 10000):
            for j in range(0, 10000):
                for k in range(0, 10000):
                    pass

p = Pool()
p.imap_unordered(worker, range(10))
p.close()
p.join()
```

Comment: Thanks, I would like to give you more upvotes. You just forgot to add the class instance "c" before calling maFunction().